# Python if/else and elif

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

When I run the code below, I get a `SyntaxError`.  Can anyone help me figure this out. Thank you

```
mien = 'beautiful' 

if mien = 'stupid':
   print ('you are stupid')
   else:
       if mien = 'beautiful':
       print ('you are right, thank you!')
       else: #line16
           print ('Opps!')
```

Here is the error message:

```
>File "..\Playground\", line 16     
>    else:     
>       ^     
>SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation. From your sample (as edited by @jonsca) the error is above the line you say. BTW, you use `==` for equality ... so `if mien == 'stupid':` and etc...

Comment: Your example does not give the error you posted. It shows a syntax error on line 3 `if mien = 'stupid':` Please run the example you post!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `==` operator to test equality. Also, you can use the `elif` keyword, like this:

```
mien = 'beautiful'
if mien == 'stupid':
    print('you are stupid')
elif mien == 'beautiful':
    print('you are right, thank you!')
else:
    print('Opps!')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mien = 'beautiful'
if mien == 'stupid':
    print ('you are stupid')
else:
    if mien == 'beautiful':
        print ('you are right, thank you!')
    else:
        print ('Opps!')
```

You forgot to use "==" for comparison in IF statement.

[image]

Comment: SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Comment: @emsnguyen You cannot copy and paste compound statements in the interactive IDLE.

Comment: File "..\Playground\", line 2 
    if mien == 'stupid': 
    ^ 
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: still I am not sure where I am going wrong, IDLE is quite different from what I learn in sololearn. My version is 3.5.2

Comment: My Version is also 3.5. But I used Pycharm. I Attached a screenshot also.